# Custom Link - Individual URL Links per Image - Elementor Gallery

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I use the following code to Add Individual URL Links per Image in elementor

if I have several galleries on the same page, how can it be indicated that it refers to a specific e-gallery-item, or what parameter needs to be changed in the code?
The post number or something else? What code do I need instead?

```
        `<style>.e-gallery-item{cursor: pointer;} </style>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var filteredImages = document.querySelectorAll('.e-gallery-item');
        var links = [
        'https://www.domain-name.com/1',
        'https://www.domain-name.com/2',
        'https://www.domain-name.com/3'
         ];
         var _loope = function _loope(i) {
         filteredImages[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
         location = links[i];
         });
         };
         for (var i = 0; i < filteredImages.length; i++) {
         _loope(i);
         }
         });
         </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit older, but maybe this answer will help someone later.

In the case of several galleries, it is necessary to name the specific gallery where you want to apply URLs with the attribute ID or CLASS (in Elementor, you can find it in the Advanced tab), e.g.

```
.my_gallery
```

You will then change the given code:

```
.e-gallery-item
```

on the:

```
.my_gallery .e-gallery-item
```